# What is the meaning of "question of when not if "?

Tags: meaning-in-context, negation, interrogatives

> Scotland voted heavily against #Brexit. question of when not if a new referendum is put forward & passes, as people will choose EU over UK

[Source.](https://twitter.com/RichardHaass/status/746184203105091584)

I don't understand "question of when not if ",can you explain it ? thanks.

Comment: This **will** happen, the only question is when it will.

Answer (score 1):

The "not if" part implies that putting a new referendum forward is *not* a hypothetical scenario. He believed that a new referendum **will** be put forward.

So, you can rephrase it as

> (This is a) question of **when** a new referendum is put forward passes, as people will choose EU over UK

It is a "question" because I'm guessing that at the time that he made the tweet, the results were not in yet.

Though I usually hear "matter" not "question" used,

> (This is a) matter of **when** a new referendum is put forward passes, as people will choose EU over UK

This means that it **will** happen and the matter is *when*.

So I guess the above could also be phrased as

> The question is "**when** will it happen?", not "will it happen?".